# How do I write MIPS code for vector multiplication

Tags: cpu-architecture, cpu-registers, mips32, qtspim, smips

Define vector `mul(vector v, float t)`. It returns a vector by multiplying it by t.

If `a=4i+3j+12k` then `mul(a,0.5)` will return `2i+1.5j+6k`.

Here's the code I've written:

```
.globl main
.text

main:
    la $s0,t                 #loading t into s1
    lw $s1,0($s0)             
    ori $s2,$zero,0     
    la $s3,v
    #la $s0,v
    #lw $s3,0($s0)
    la $s0,s
    lw $s4,0($s0)
    jal f

f:
    #if <cond>
    bge $s2,$s4,DONE
    #<for body>
    lw $s5, 0($s3)
    mul $s3,$s3,$s1 
    li $v0,10
    syscall
    j UPDATE

UPDATE:
    addi $s2,$s2,1    #i=i+1
    addi $s3,$s3,4    #moving address 4 bytes since int
    j f

DONE:

    li $v0,10
    syscall
    .data
    s: .word 3
    v: .word 4 3 12         #hard coding vector coefficients
    t: .word 2              #value to be multiplied by
```

When I run this on SPIM simulator, the registers don't produce any value. Is my code wrong or do I need to add something?

Answer (score 0):

```
    mul $s3,$s3,$s1 : this instruction is wrong because $s3 register contains the address of the vector and no the value .
```

`li $v0,10 ; syscall` And remove these lines just ahead the jump to UPDATE .

Otherwise , a program will multiply only once

```
.data
  s: .word 3
  v: .word 14 3 12         #hard coding vector coefficients
  t: .word 2              #value to be multiplied by

.globl main
.text

main:
  la $s0,t                 #loading t into $s0
   lw $s1,0($s0)             # $s1=2          
   ori $s2,$zero,0           # $s2=0
   la $s3,v                 # loading v into $s3
   li $s7,0

   la $s0,s                 # loading s into $s0
  lw $s4,0($s0)           # $s4 = 3
  j f

 f:
  #if <cond>
  bge $s2,$s4,DONE        
  #<for body>
  lw $s5, ($s3)            # $s5= 4
  mulu $s5,$s5,$s1 
  addu $s7,$s7,$s5         # result stored into $s7

 j UPDATE

UPDATE:
  addiu $s2,$s2,1    #i=i+1
  addiu $s3,$s3,4    #moving address 4 bytes since int
  j f

DONE:

  li $v0,10
  syscall
```

Comment: thank you so much! i tried it out on my computer and it works!!